# Nokia Application Distribution

Tags: distribution, nokia

I am making an application for Nokia phone using J2ME.

I want to know how to distribute my Nokia application.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to distribution

1.) **Get your app signed**

You need to sign your app so that it can installed on nokia phones. There are three levels of signing [Open signed, Express signed, Certified signed]. In most cases you Express signing will work for you. You will find all details [here](https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page). https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page.

2.) **Rollout your application**

After your application is signed, you can start selling for a price that you can decide. I'd recommend [Nokia OVI store](https://store.ovi.com/#/applications?sortBy=mostPopular&contentArea=applications&priceType=paid) and [Handango](http://www.handango.com) for distributing your app for online sell.